# How to enable failed login profle on MySQL

Tags: mysql, security, mysql-5.7, logins

We are trying to implement failed_login profile for account lock on MySQL. didn't find it on documentation.

Our version is 5.7.12.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MySQL supports database/logon triggers as other DBMS do. At least I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. So that "usual way" is ruled out here.

But apparently you can do it [via the general server log](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/). Set the location of the log in your option file with

```
general_log_file = /where/you/want/it
```

and set

```
log_warnings = 2
```

. That will log warnings about unsuccessful logins.

Set

```
general_log = 1
```

when you also want to log successful logins.

However be aware, that this will mean, that a lot of other stuff is logged too. It's all just about raising or lowering log levels here, not specifically setting login related logging.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answers, however... is there any ready script for the purpose.